# Cosa vuol dire "appiattiti" in questo passaggio?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> I ragazzi s'erano fermati tutti insieme e anche loro mordicchiavano, susine o dita, o cicatrici che avevano sulle mani o sulle braccia, o lembi dei sacchi. E pian piano, dalle loro bocche mordicchianti, quasi costretti per vincere un disagio, non spinti da un vero sentimento, se mai desiderosi d'essere contraddetti, principiarono a dire frasi quasi senza voce, che suonavano in cadenza come se cercassero di cantare: – Cosa sei... venuta a fare... Sinforosa... ora ritorni... non sei più... no stra compagna... ah, ah, ah... ah, vigliacca... 
>         Uno sfrascar sui rami ed ecco, da un alto fico affaccia il capo Cosimo, tra foglia e foglia, ansando. Lei, di sotto in su, con quel frustino in bocca, guardava lui e loro **appiattiti** tutti nello stesso sguardo.

Potreste spiegarmi qual è il significato di "appiattiti" in questo passaggio? Ho cercato il verbo "appiattire" in alcuni dizionari, ma non sono riuscita a trovare nulla che abbia senso in questo contesto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il significato figurato di *appiattire* è "eliminare le differenze", "livellare", "uniformare" (http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/A/appiattire.shtml). Nel brano che hai citato, si può intendere o che Viola guardava Cosimo e i ragazzini tutti insieme senza notare le differenze tra di loro o che Cosimo e i ragazzini la guardavano nello stesso modo.